# $x_{k+3}=k3^k+5k-2,k\ge0$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis

Find all the sequences $(x_k)_{k\ge0}$ that satisfy: $x_{k+3}=k3^k+5k-2,k\ge0$. Can somebody give me some tips, please?

Comment: What have you tried? What do you know about these kinds of problems?

Comment: I don't understand the problem.  For $n\geq3$ we are given an explicit formula for $x_n$.  $x_0,x_1,x_2$ can be anything at all.  Are you sure you've copied the formula correctly?

Comment: Yes, this is the formula. It's from the Discrete Systems lecture